# Reading CSV file from Node.js (Used to work with python)

Tags: python, node.js, csv, parsing

I am trying to read csv file from nodejs like what I did with python.

Here is my python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7
import os
import time
import pandas as pd

from pathlib import Path

addresses_df = pd.read_csv(
    'snapshot.txt',
    header=None, names=['id', 'address', 'balance']
)

for row in addresses_df.itertuples():
    print("Address:",row.address,"Balance:",balance)
```

and here is my csv file

```
0,0x843fd22c88d59e57ae1856a871a5d95e95b0a656,52500000000000
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const fastCsv = require('fast-csv')

fs.createReadStream('test.csv')
    .pipe(fastCsv.parse({ headers: false }))
    .on('data', row => {
        const [id, address, balance] = row
        console.log('address: %s, balance: %s', address, balance)
    })
```

output

```
address: 0x843fd22c88d59e57ae1856a871a5d95e95b0a656, balance: 52500000000000
```